# Birth Bracha Question

Tags: blessing, pregnancy-birth

What Bracha do you make on the birth of a child? What Bracha is made on a Boy? What Bracha on a Girl? When is this Bracha Made?

Comment: What about a blessing when you find out the gender of the fetus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that HaTov vehameitiv is said upon hearing "you have a new son!"

And shehechiyanu is made upon seeing your new baby daughter. Rav Moshe Feinstein says your new daughter is certainly no worse than a good friend you haven't seen in a while, which also warrants a shehechiyanu.

Comment: any exact sources does everyone agree

Comment: Hatov vehameitiv for a boy: Shulchan Aruch, Orach Chaim 223:1. Shehecheyanu for a girl: Mishnah Berurah ibid. :2.

Comment: You can only say Shehechiyanu on a friend if you have seen them once before and then there was a gap. Meeting a "pen pal" doesn't count. [Shulchan Arukh 225:2](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%94#.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.91)

Comment: @DoubleAA See _MB_ 5 there.

Comment: @msh210 Yes. Quite the Chiddush about a case that existed 2000 years ago but wasn't mentioned until 200 years ago. The silence is indeed deafening.

Comment: What is the good news that the HaTov vehameitiv is on? That the wife survived? That the baby came out alive? That the baby is healthy? That the gender of the fetus turned out to have been male?

Answer (score 4):

The gemara says that you can say Hatov vehameitiv when you have a son. It also says you can say that same bracha on any 'besorot tovot' (good tidings). Both of these rulings are quoted in the Shulchan Aruch (OC [222:1](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9729&st=&pgnum=716) and [223:1](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9729&st=&pgnum=717)). In my experience, hearing about a daughter's birth is pretty top-quality good tidings.

Comment: http://ramban.org.il/%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%AA-%D7%94%D7%98%D7%95%D7%91-%D7%95%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%98%D7%99%D7%91-%D7%91%D7%94%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%93%D7%AA-%D7%91%D7%AA/

Comment: http://www.betmidrash.org.il/index.php/%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%95%D7%93%D7%99%D7%94_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%94%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%93%D7%AA_%D7%91%D7%AA

Comment: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=25136&st=&pgnum=19&hilite=

Comment: [http://hebrew.yoatzot.org/question.php?id=5955](https://web.archive.org/web/20100707135434/http://www.yoatzot.org/question.php?id=5955)

Comment: http://shut.moreshet.co.il/shut2.asp?id=64145

Comment: http://www.inn.co.il/Articles/Article.aspx/12004

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20685&pgnum=151

Comment: https://harova.org/torah/view.asp?id=1726

Comment: Olat Yitzchak 3:77

Comment: Does this edit mean you get a mazal tov?

Comment: https://torahclarity.blogspot.com/2022/05/baruch-hatov-vehameitiv.html