# Why Hatov V'Hameitiv for son?

Tags: pregnancy-birth, shehecheyanu

The Maharil (Milah 1:p.65) [writes](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14721&st=&pgnum=130&hilite=)

> נראה בעיני הטעם משום דאי׳ בגמרא אמרו לו אשתו ילדה זכר מברך הטוב והמטיב
> וי״מ משום ארבעה צריכין להודות ואחד מהם היוצא מבית האסורים וכן התינוק
> יצא כן מאסורי מעי אמו - The Gemara says a woman who gives birth to a
> son says Hatov V'Hameitiv, and there are commentators who explain this
> is because it is simlar to the four who must praise Hashem for being
> saved, including one who emerged from prison, as this baby emerged
> from the prison of his mother's womb.

Seemingly according to this understanding, why shouldn't we say Hatov V'hameitiv for a daughter as well, rather than shehechiyanu as mentioned by the [Mishna Berura 223:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.223.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=bi) and [others](https://shulchanaruchharav.com/halacha/saying-the-blessing-of-shehechiyanu-upon-the-birth-of-a-daughter/).

Comment: The false comparison to Shehechiyanu said on seeing a new daughter is both incredibly misleading and distracting and should be removed immediately! https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/114563/759

Comment: @DoubleAA Thank you! Never realized they're completely separate - it seemed like they were somewhat connected https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/6676/13811

Comment: @DoubleAA Some Rabbonim seem to even try explaining why there is a shehechiyanu for the daughter vs. the hatov for the son in the way I initially imagined https://www.ou.org/life/torah/mm_blessing_on_the_birth_of_a_baby/

Comment: That's all fabricated with no classical precedent to try and justify a questionable and politically-incorrect-sounding position.

Comment: @DoubleAA I hear you, that's just where my misunderstanding likely stemmed from. He's published with Feldheim, OU, Aish, etc. Not saying that makes it right - it just means you'll have more people like me to explain this to. (I'll try to help)

Answer (score 1):

You skipped the first bit of the statement and have misunderstood him. He is not explaining the obligation of Hatov Vehameitiv by comparison to those who say Hagomel. Rather, he is giving two reasons for praising God at the circumcision ceremony. Note the ו in וי״מ. Here's the whole quote with some elaboration in translation for clarity:

> אומרים קיים את הילד הזה לאביו ולאמו וגו׳ עד הודו לה׳ כי טוב כי לעולם חסדו. נראה בעיני הטעם משום דאי׳ בגמרא אמרו לו אשתו ילדה זכר מברך הטוב והמטיב וי״מ משום ארבעה צריכין להודות ואחד מהם היוצא מבית האסורים וכן התינוק יצא כן מאסורי מעי אמו
> We say at the circumcision [the prayer](https://www.sefaria.org/Siddur_Edot_HaMizrach%2C_Assorted_Blessings_and_Prayers%2C_Brit_Mila.39) "...Establish this child to his father and mother..." etc. until the verse "Hodu...". It seems to me the reason [for including the praise "Hodu..."] is because the Gemara said when someone tells you your wife birthed a male child he should bless God [and no one does that nowadays but instead we say this verse which is thematically parallel]. And others explain the reason [for including the praise "Hodu..."] is because we know 4 are obligated to offer thanks, one of whom is he who leaves a prison, and this child left the prison of his mother's gut [so praise of thanks is appropriate].